# save string to parse array in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a column in my parse table that i want to store names in when a user accepts another user, so it is one string at a time.

The column is called "passengers"  and the string I am trying to store is an Id.

I successfully get the correct Id but saving it to the column in parse is my problem.

Here is my code

```
   var appendToPassengerArrayQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                        appendToPassengerArrayQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(cell.postIdLabel.text!, block: {
                            (object:PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


                          // this is where I want to send the id to the array in the column of the correct post
                           object["passengers"] = userId
                            object?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                                (success: Bool, error: NSError?)-> Void in
                            if (success) {
                                println("request deleted")

                            }
                            else {
                                println("cannot delete")
                                }}
                        })
```

The error I am getting is on the line `object["passengers"] = userId`

This is the error message **`cannot assign value type string to a value of type anyobject`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because `object: PFObject?` is still unwrapped which means its value can be a `nil or PFObject`.

```
    var appendToPassengerArrayQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    appendToPassengerArrayQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(cell.postIdLabel.text!, block: {
        (object:PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            object!["passengers"] = userId
            object!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?)-> Void in
                if (success) {
                    println("request deleted")
                }
                else {
                    println("cannot delete")
                }}
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this code actually works the issue now is i get this error. Any thoughts? In my question i did mention that what I am trying to save is a string into the array. 

[Error]: invalid type for key passengers, expected array, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.2)

Comment: object["passengers"] = userId should object?.addObject(userId!, forKey: "passengers") in order to save the string to the array in parse